# Redis Pub/Sub when a sub is part of a autoscaling group

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, autoscaling

I am looking at Redis pubsub with consumers being a part of a 2-4 node autoscaling group (HA reasons)

Maybe i am missing something obvious but is there some mechanism in Redis pubsub which manages duplicates being received by the subscriber/consumer?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is also no guarantee that a message will be received.
You can add logic on your client side. (implement serial number/id to your messages, and ack mechanism)